# Facebook FQL not working under application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a FQL(Facebook) query running to get all the movies list from my friends.

**Query :**

"*SELECT uid,name,movies FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =  me())*"

I have tested the application under **Graph API Explorer** ,its working but when i shift query to my application it doesn't work.

I have *Enabled the permissions* also , namely **user_about_me**, **friends_about_me**, **friends_likes**, **user_likes** , **user_interests** ,**friends_interests**.

Added *Extended Permission* : **read_stream** , **read_requests**.

Can anybody help in this !!

Comment: Are you positive your application is returning results from FQL in general? Which SDK and language are you using?

Comment: @rudolf_franek yes i am getting uid and name from the above query.Am using PHP SDK.
Under Graph API Explorer [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), when i choose my application in application list ,its not providing me the movies list .But if i choose Graph Api Explorer in same list, it works !!

Comment: Are you using the same access token as in the GRAPH explorer ?

Comment: Ian, there seems to be issue with facebook call from my application its been resolved for now.
And yes you need to have **All the above mentioned permission** for retrieving the movies name .